# Wordpress меняет имена файлов в медиафайлах

Tags: wordpress

Столкнулся с проблемой в медиафайлах. 
При загрузки файлов, Wordpress меняет им имена на цифровые. Не важно какое имя было, становится 1, 2, 3, 4 и тд. И каждый раз счет начинается с 1. Возникает куча проблем с миниатюрами, так как они все становятся 1,2,3 и т.д. 
Как это исправить? Не хочу что бы Wordpress менял имена файлов. WordPress 4.3.1

Comment: Какие плагины установлены? Пробовали без них?

Comment: Плагины только те, которые идут с темой. Связался с их сапортом, говоря, что это делает Wordpress

Comment: tutankhamun - спасибо я нашел деверсанта. им и правда оказался плагин MD Translate URL. Только зачем он лезит в картинки это вопрос. Тему можно удалить.

Comment: Лучше оставьте свой комментарий в виде ответа. Подобная проблема может возникнуть еще у кого-нибудь. Обязательно укажите версию плагина. Возможно позже это исправят.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему я решил, отключил MD Translate URL версия 3.5
Зачем-то этот плагин пытался переименовать медиафайлы не содержащие русского названия.